# Use Openstack on multiple physical servers

Tags: openstack

I would like to know if we could make use of openstack to build a private server farm e.g. with 9  physical servers with different hardware specifications in prod site. Does the attached picture correctly describe the case? Is it feasible? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzmfC.jpg)

Comment: This is exactly what OpenStack is for: Create a cloud on a number of servers, then launch virtual machines in this cloud. Servers don't need to have identical characteristics, although it makes your live much easier if they do. However, depending on your requirements, OpenStack may be overkill. There are simpler, yet still powerful environments like Proxmox or Ovirt. List your requirements, then compare them with the feature set of various virtualization and cloud solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The setup you're trying to make is feasible.

And you can establish network connectivity among all your VMs following instructions on below link -
https://docs.openstack.org/security-guide/networking/architecture.html

Alternatively, you can use an architecture featuring OpenStack installation on top of Kubernetes using containers.
[Here’s](https://fuel-ccp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/design/ref_arch_1000_nodes.html) a useful documentation on that.